# To measure the dimensions of the Yolo detected object. ex. Height, width, distance from camera

Tags: ros, yolo

I am using ubuntu 16.04 with ROS kinetic. For my project work I have detected the door and door handle with YOLO darknet. For that I am using intel realsense d435 camera.

Now my questions are as follow :

How can I measure the distance between door and the camera.

How can I measure the height and width of the door.

How can I add the detected door in rviz 3d.

Answer (score 0):

(1) How can I measure the distance between door and the camera.

PCL sample census see pcl sample. It will give you ax+by+cz+d=0
The actual perpendicular distance should be the d.

[image]

(2) How can I measure the height and width of the door.

Sample consensus result to get inliner and then determine the priciple direction using PCA or anymeans necessary. The based do dominant direction, measure the max and min alone the dominant direction. That should give you height. Do the same for the width

(3) How can I add the detected door in rviz 3d.
Same detect and publish

Below is the a short sample or how you do it

```
ros::Publisher pub;

float deg2rad(float alpha)
{
  return (alpha * 0.017453293f);
}

void ransac(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr input, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_projected)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  *cloud = *input;

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr floor_coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients());
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr floor_indices(new pcl::PointIndices());
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> floor_finder;
  floor_finder.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
  floor_finder.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PARALLEL_PLANE);
  // floor_finder.setModelType (SACMODEL_PLANE);
  floor_finder.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  floor_finder.setMaxIterations(300);
  floor_finder.setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1));
  floor_finder.setDistanceThreshold(0.08);
  floor_finder.setEpsAngle(deg2rad(5));
  floor_finder.setInputCloud(boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(*cloud));
  floor_finder.segment(*floor_indices, *floor_coefficients);

  if (floor_indices->indices.size() > 0)
  {
    // Extract the floor plane inliers
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr floor_points(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extractor;
    extractor.setInputCloud(boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(*cloud));
    extractor.setIndices(floor_indices);
    extractor.filter(*floor_points);
    extractor.setNegative(true);
    extractor.filter(*cloud);

    // Project the floor inliers
    pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZRGB> proj;
    proj.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    proj.setInputCloud(floor_points);
    proj.setModelCoefficients(floor_coefficients);
    proj.filter(*cloud_projected);

    floor_points->header.frame_id = "camera_link";
    floor_points->header.stamp = ros::Time::now().toNSec();
   }
}

void passthrough_z(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_passthrough)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, *cloud);

    // Create the filtering object
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud (boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(*cloud));
    pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
    pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 6.0);
    pass.filter (*cloud_passthrough);
}

void passthrough_y(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_passthrough)
{
    // Create the filtering object
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud (boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(*cloud_passthrough));
    pass.setFilterFieldName ("y");
    pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 5.0);
    pass.filter (*cloud_passthrough);
}

void passthrough_x(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_passthrough)
{
    // Create the filtering object
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud (boost::make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(*cloud_passthrough));
    pass.setFilterFieldName ("x");
    pass.setFilterLimits (-2.0, 2.0);
    pass.filter (*cloud_passthrough);
}

void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  // Do data processing here...

  // run pass through filter to shrink point cloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_passthrough(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  passthrough_z(input, cloud_passthrough);
  passthrough_y(cloud_passthrough);
  passthrough_x(cloud_passthrough);

  // run ransac to find floor
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_projected(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  ransac(cloud_passthrough, cloud_projected);
  pub.publish(*cloud_projected);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "pcl_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("camera/depth_registered/points", 1, cloud_cb);

  // Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
  pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```